# lotus notes, search data that equal to textbox

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus-formula

I don't understand why my code is not allowed.

```
@If(@DbLookup("":"nocache";@DbName;"GPA";1)="GPnum";@Failure(@Command([FileSave])&@Command([CloseWindow]));@Success)`
```

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: what is the problem with it?

Comment: There are multiple problems in this.   It appears you don't understand at-Failure and at-Success, nor the at-Do function.   What is the outcome you want here?  [typing at function names in the comments not allowed due to the system thinking they are notification syntax]

Comment: SAj, do you know a way how to check data in a database ? and check if the value of the data is excise  ? thank.

Comment: @LyodMichael I suspect English is not your first language.  I do not understand what you are asking.

Comment: yes im not, sorry, can you help me to fix my code or give me some advice how to? thank you

Comment: As noted below, it would be best if you told us what you want to accomplish instead of just showing us the code. Likely, there is a better way to accomplish what you're trying to accomplish than this.

Answer (score 0):

```
@If(@DbLookup("":"nocache";@DbName;"GPA";1)="GPnum"
```

your code should have 1 more parameter.

from help

```
@DbLookup( class : cache ; server : database ; view ; key ; fieldName ; keywords )
```

So you have "GPA" as view and then you need to specify **Key** and **field/column** you wish to return. Also for DbLookup I would recommend you to use [FAILSILENT] as keywords, in this case you will not need to check result for @IsError

However probably you just need to use @DbColumn instead of @DbLookup.

as I understood you need to verify if some value exists in database/view, try this code:

```
@If(@DbColumn("":"NoCache";@DbName;"GPA";1)="GPnum"; @Failure(@Command([FileSave]) : @Command([CloseWindow])); @Success)
```

or

```
@If(@DbLookup("":"NoCache";@DbName;"GPA"; "GPnum"; 1; [FAILSILENT])<>""; @Failure(@Command([FileSave]) : @Command([CloseWindow])); @Success)
```

Comment: sir it's not working. it say to many argument in database function.

Comment: sir, can i ask? possible to find if the data is unique when i save in a database? this is my first application in lotus script but i think i cant make it, with out help from the professionals.

Comment: nothings happen when i click the action button, but when i change the dblookup into dbcolumn the message says to many argument in database function

Comment: with DbLookup nothing happens with there is no value GPnum in view.
with DbColumn u got this issue because DbLookup ad DbColumn has different number of arguments, and I wrote about 2 different line of code for DbLookup ad DbColumn.

Comment: sir, last question. what is the difference between dblookup and dbcolumn sir? and it was appropriate to use them to track the duplication of data?

Comment: please read manual, that is what you should do before you started to ask for help.
dblookup - http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/Rnext/help6_designer.nsf/0/4d1d4f061d97527185256c54004bfb35?OpenDocument
dbcolumn - http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/rnext/help6_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/f0a22f1e07b2507f85256c54004bf9d6?OpenDocument

Comment: @Dmytro I think you wanted ="" instead of <>"" in your last code example.

Comment: I do not think so, if dblookup returns result means we found something and then we should execute code...

Comment: Okay... If he really wants atFailure when the search does find a match, then you are right.  But he's saving the current document in the atFailure call, and something sure doesn't seem right about that.  In one of the comments he asked about checking if a value is unique in the database, therefore if the search finds a non-blank value I suspect he does not want the new document to be saved.  It is hard to tell what he really wants, though.

Comment: Another complication for uniqueness testing is that if the current document has already been saved prior to the validation running (i.e., if the user saves more than once), then you need to check to see if the atDblookup is actually returning the current document.  I usually use the [ReturnDocumentUniqueId] flag for that.

Comment: "It is hard to tell what he really wants"
> you got a point :)

Comment: good day sir richard, i read your comment and it its possible to find value before i save my data?

Comment: sir, question? if i set the nocatch to recatch what will happen?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I add a code for button action that save the current doc (see author comment below)
The editable field in which the user enters the value we check is called GPnum. A view "GPA" is sorted by its first col an display GPnum value.

```
t:=@DbLookup("":"nocache";@DbName;"GPA"; GPnum ; 1 ; [FailSilent] );
@If(@IsError(t) ; @Prompt([Ok]; "DB has a problem:";@Text(t)) ;
  t = "" ; @Do(@Command([FileSave]);@Command([CloseWindow])) ;
  @Prompt([Ok] ; "unable to save" ; "The key already exists") )
```

original response

```
t:=@DbLookup("":"nocache";@DbName;"GPA"; @ThisValue ; 1 );
@If(@IsError(t) ; @Failure("DB has a problem:"+@Text(t)) ; t =  "" ; @Success ; @Failure("The key already exists") )
```

If you use @failure/@success you MUST be in an editable field in a form (validation).
As I understand you check that your value does not ALREADY exists.
so:

**first** add @thisValue as the key you search in the DBLOOKUP,
as told above DBLOOKUP could return an error thus check @isError(t)

**second** failure just BLOCK the validation of the form, I never tried (an it doesn't make sense) to make it save the form

Hope it helps

Comment: thank you sir, i will try it. i give you some update for the result thx again.

Comment: sir, there is nothing happening, sir by the way I putting this code in action button.

Comment: BUT !!! @failure is **not** for action button! I edit my response since I think I better understand what you want to do (I hope... your question is not very clear)

Comment: sir, the messagebox says db has a problem. and i add " ; " in the end of the second line sir. " entry not found in index or view index not built.

Comment: 1- Answer edited: You're right I corrected ";" at second line.Now I added the [FAILSILENT], you will no more get "the entry not found in index" and it will save your doc.
2- t is a temporal variable

Comment: sir, i try to enter id 10 and it was save yes thank, but i try again to add id 10 and it was save again. the searching is not working, sir.

Comment: sir, thank you so much much. thank you sir, can i ask again some favor for you. :) i love you sir.

Comment: This time I build a mini DB, I corrected my post. If you have a problem this time, please give me a mail where I can send the DB.

Comment: DB sent, NB this is "for prove only" ! I mean be a aware that: 
 - user can save with CTRL+S without your button !
 - I don't allow saving a second time the doc. See [ReturnDocumentUniqueId] remark from @Richard Schwartz

Comment: sir, what version of domino lotus notes are you using, the mini database that you send it says that version not supported im using 8.5.3v sir. thank you again sir.